# How to define a Nuxt link in a Vuetify button when portion of the path belongs to $route.params?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

In Nuxt and Vuetify application, I have a series of buttons:

```js
<v-btn dark color="orange" href="className/studentName" nuxt>
  <v-icon large left>favorite</v-icon>
  studentName
</v-btn>
```

I want to refactor this code knowing that I get className from the route: `$route.params.className` And I get studentName from a normal JavaScript array.

When I type href={{$route.params.className}}/studentName I get an error:

> Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of
>
> , use .

And when I do it that way:

```
:href="$route.params.className/studentName"
```

I get this error instead:

> Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "href". Expected String,
> Object, got Number.

So how to define correctly my `href` prop without hard writing `className` (I mean I want to use `$route.params.className` in order to refactor my code which has several buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a statement such as the following to evaluate the route param value and append the string `/studentName`:

```
:href="$route.params.className + '/studentName'"
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 30):

You should use `to="studentName" nuxt`

For example:

```
 <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and">
    <v-btn flat to="/home" nuxt> Home </v-btn>
    <v-btn flat to="/contact" nuxt> Contact </v-btn>
    <v-btn flat to="/login" nuxt> Login </v-btn>
 </v-toolbar-items>
```

Comment: Please elaborate

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons/
It shows to use `nuxt` as stated

Comment: Docs: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props (search `nuxt`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-bind:href=className+"/"+studentName` in order to get this working. You can find a working code at https://codepen.io/mohithg/pen/yxRabK